# Python and Paramiko to copy directory to target machine

Tags: python, paramiko

I am using Python and Paramiko to copy directory to target machine.
Instead of using only IP like

`ssh.connect('xx.xx.xx.xx', username='usr', password='pwd')`

I want to use as `ssh.connect('root@xx.xx.xx.xx', username='usr', password='pwd')` like this but it's not working.

Is there any Python way to copy directory from source machine to destination folder along with user name and password?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pexpect**

http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html

```
from pexpect import pxssh
import getpass
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')
    username = raw_input('username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    s.login(hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline('uptime')   # run a command
    s.prompt()             # match the prompt
    print(s.before)        # print everything before the prompt.
    s.sendline('ls -l')
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)
    s.sendline('df')
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("pxssh failed on login.")
    print(e)
```